# How do I modify this where clause to check if a column has a nil value in SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following query:

```
user.all_memberships.where("user_id = ? OR invited_id = ?", user2.id, user2.id)
```

This is what my `membership` model looks like:

```
#<Membership id: 4, family_tree_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-10-23 20:33:41", updated_at: "2015-10-23 20:33:41", relation: nil, invited_id: nil>
```

What I would like the query to also check is if `relation != nil`....but not sure how to represent that in the SQL passed in to the `where` clause in quotes.

In other words, I would like for it to check for the presence of `user2.id` in either the `user_id` or `invited_id` column. But...`relation` also has to be NOT nil.

How do I do that?

**Edit 1**

When I do the following query, as per Blindy's suggestion below:

```
user.all_memberships.where("relation is not null and user_id = ? OR invited_id = ?", user2.id, user2.id)
```

It generates this query, that seems to work but based on the SQL it generates I am nervous about it. Notice the second AND and the second part of that statement. It feels like it may return false positives occasionally.

```
(0.9ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "memberships" WHERE (memberships.user_id = 1 OR memberships.invited_id = 1) AND (relation is not null and user_id = 2 OR invited_id = 2)
```

How do I customize the AR `where` query to be more true to what I want to do and not have any hidden gotchas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't completely clear, but I think you mean something like:

```
relation is not null and (user_id = ? OR invited_id = ?)
```

Comment: So far this works. It generates this SQL statement: `(0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "memberships"  WHERE (memberships.user_id = 1 OR memberships.invited_id = 1) AND (relation is not null and user_id = 2 OR invited_id = 2)`. Notice the second `AND` and the second part of that statement. It feels like it may return false positives occassionally...am I wrong?

Comment: Yep it's wrong, it's stripping out the parentheses. I'd replace the library too terrible to handle such a simple query.

Comment: I am using ActiveRecord so that is quite literally not possible to replace the library.